# Datatables get drawn data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to retrieve the data from my table which is drwan to the screen.

I am able to get the table data on each redraw, however it is the full dataset rather than what is drawn to the screen.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'excel',
                text: 'Download Excel'
            }
        ]
    });     
    $('#myTable').on('draw.dt', function (){
        console.log(table.data());
    });
    $('#search-category').bind('input propertychange',function(){
        table
        .column(3)
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
    }),
    $('#search-sub-category').bind('input propertychange', function(){
        table
        .column(4)
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
    })
} );
```

My aim is to get on each redraw, the table data which is actually shown to the user.

https://jsfiddle.net/qbcnsjo8/

Comment: How is data inputted? Surely you could just store that data before input and then keep it to one side to use later on.

Comment: The idea is that when the table is filtered, the resulting data can be edited client side in javascript. Rather than storing the filter terms and re-filtering the full dataset, I assume datatables includes this functionality and didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`rows().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()) API method to retrieve data for some or all rows based on specific criteria.

To retrieve data for rows with search applied:

```
table.rows({ search: 'applied' }).data();
```

To retrieve data for rows on current page with search applied:

```
table.rows({ 'page': 'current', search: 'applied' }).data();
```

From the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()):

> The order of the data in the returned array and which rows the data is obtained from (searched rows, visible rows etc) is controlled by the [`selector-modifier`](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier) option of the [`rows()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows()) selector used to get the selected rows.

See [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/qbcnsjo8/3/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Cheers, perfect solution. I overlooked this and was playing with :https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector#{integer}:visIdx